# Unable to insert row with Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, google-api, google-sheets

I am trying to follow the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) to generate a worksheet with data in an existing spreadsheet. I am able to establish a connection, access the desired spreadsheet, create new worksheets, and various other things. However, when I try to use my SpreadsheetService object to create a row, even with the code verbatim from the [**Add a list row** section](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data) of the API, I am getting an error.

Using the provided code at the link above, I get the error at the line `service.insert(listFeed, row);`:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException' occurred in Google.GData.Client.dll

Additional information: Execution of request failed:
```

Then, under 'execution of request failed', is a link to a feed of the worksheet I am using, which fails whether it is a blank worksheet just created or an existing worksheet. This link is shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I correctly insert a row into a worksheet?